# Cant able to select value from "TO" drop down

Tags: selenium

```
element click intercepted: Element <label for="toCity">...</label> is not clickable at point (511, 254). Other element would receive the click: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open react-autosuggest__input--focused" placeholder="To" value="">
```

I cant able to select value from "TO" drop down
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LGxI.png)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();
WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hsw_autocomplePopup autoSuggestPlugin']/div/input"));
source.clear();
source.sendKeys("mumbai");
Thread.sleep(2000);
source.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='react-autosuggest__suggestions-list']/li/div/div/p[contains(text(),'Mumbai, India')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label")).click();
WebElement destination=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='react-autosuggest__container react-autosuggest__container--open'] //input[@placeholder='To']"));
destination.clear();
destination.sendKeys("DEL");
Thread.sleep(2000);
destination.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
destination.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='react-autosuggest__suggestions-list']/li/div/div/p[contains(text(),'Bengaluru, India')]")).click();
```